# Android app crashes when i use FeedListAdapter for ListView on Android 4.4 only

Tags: java, android

This is the feedlist adapter. When i call this from the activity the app crashes on Android 4.4 but the code works fine on 5.0 and above. Please help. Been trying to fix this for about a week now with no luck. The app crashes on this link 
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
 public class FeedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Activity activity;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
        private SharedPreferences mAdminPreferences;


        public FeedListAdapter(Activity activity, List<FeedItem> feedItems) {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.feedItems = feedItems;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return feedItems.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int location) {
            return feedItems.get(location);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (inflater == null)
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null)
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);

            final TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            final TextView projectid = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.project_id);
            TextView timestamp = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
            final TextView statusMsg = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtStatusMsg);
            final TextView url = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtUrl);
            // final TextView usertype = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.usertype);



            FeedItem item = feedItems.get(position);


            name.setText(item.getName());
            projectid.setText(item.getId());
            url.setText(item.getUrl());

            final String userid = (item.getUserid());
            final String story = (item.getStory());
            final String coursename = (item.getCourseName());
            final String courseduration = (item.getCourseDuration());
            final String amount = (item.getAmount());
            final String extradetails = (item.getExtraDetails());
            final String videourl = (item.getVideoUrl());
            final String school = (item.getSchool());



            // My code to instantiate buttonclick and get name of item being clicked

            View view = convertView.findViewById(R.id.layoutclick);

            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String namegotten = name.getText().toString();
                    String projectidgotten = projectid.getText().toString();
                    String msg = statusMsg.getText().toString();
                    String urlgotten = url.getText().toString();


                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), namegotten + projectidgotten, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            Collect.getInstance().getActivityLogger()
                                    .logAction(this, "downloadBlankForms", "click");

                    Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), Activity_AllForms_Download.class);

                    i.putExtra("id", projectidgotten);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(i);

                }
            });


            // Chcek for empty status message
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getStatus())) {
                statusMsg.setText(item.getStatus());
                statusMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                // status is empty, remove from view
                statusMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            // Checking for null feed url
            if (item.getUrl() != null) {
                url.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + item.getUrl() + "\">"
                        + item.getUrl() + "</a> "));

                // Making url clickable
                url.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                url.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                // url is null, remove from the view
                url.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }


            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

Here is the LOG

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d2bb20)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: org.odk.collect.android, PID: 31036
                  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.odk.collect.android.adapters.FeedListAdapter$1
                      at org.odk.collect.android.adapters.FeedListAdapter.getView(FeedListAdapter.java:115)
                      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
                      at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1147)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                      at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1226)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                      at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:326)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                      at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Application terminated.
```

The crash ends here.

Answer (score -2):

```
My pscuode code:--

        // View view = convertView.findViewById(R.id.layoutclick);

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String namegotten = name.getText().toString();
                String projectidgotten =  projectid.getText().toString();
                String msg = statusMsg.getText().toString();
                String urlgotten = url.getText().toString();


                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), namegotten + projectidgotten, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        Collect.getInstance().getActivityLogger()
                                .logAction(this, "downloadBlankForms", "click");

                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), Activity_AllForms_Download.class);

                i.putExtra("id", projectidgotten);
                v.getContext().startActivity(i);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Tested it but it doesn't work. Thanks for the help. Still gives me the same error

Comment: Note, this works fine on other versions of android above 4.4 but doesnt work on android 4.4